# Regular expression - match numbers in a list

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list with numbers:

`2 3 11 17 21 6`

at the same time i have another list of numbers with `'-'` separator:

`-4-7-11-15-9-6-`

I need to find a regular expression in javascript that match the **first occurrence** (in this example):
`11`

Comment: /(?:^|-)11(?:-|$)/.test(str) is is really this simple?

Comment: I imagine they meant the first number that is the same in both listings.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// returns index of first occurence of element in arr
// otherwise, returns -1
var getFirstOccurence = function (arr, str) {
    // split the str by dashes and map to an array of numbers
    var t = str.split("-").map(Number);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // arr[i] is in t, return its index
        if (t.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) return i;
    }
    // otherwise, return -1 (not in list)
    return -1;
}
var str = "-4-7-11-15-9-6-",
    list = [2, 3, 11, 17, 21, 6];

alert(getFirstOccurence(list, str));
// alerts 2; arr[2] is 11, which is in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

modify the second list to `(4|7|11|15|9|6)` and use it as your pattern

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/226)

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
var string = '-4-7-11-15-9-6-',
    array = [2, 3, 11, 17, 21, 6];

var regex = new RegExp('-(' + array.join('|') + ')-');
var match = string.match(regex);
var value = match ? match[0] : undefined;
console.log()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:^|-)11(?:-|$)/
```

this regex will match 11 in front, in between and at the end